# how can i display a "é" using <h2>

Tags: html, css

I want to display a special caracter but when i used    `<h2></h2>` this caracter does not appear on the web-site page.

```
<h2>Aéroport Tunis Carthage </h2>
```

on the web-site the text is: Arport Tunis Carthage.

Comment: It's displaying:) http://jsfiddle.net/kccs8epr/

Comment: Does `é` character exist in your web font code points?

Comment: What character set are you using?

Comment: Without more information such as the font being used it's hard to help.

Comment: Are you using `UTF-8` ?

Comment: try put to head UTF-8 or maybe u using some web fonts what doesn't support diacritics.

Comment: i put <meta charset="utf-8"/> the same thing appear

Comment: `<h2>` has nothing to do with this. Typical things to check: is the encoding working properly? Does the font which the text is displayed in actually contain that character?

Answer (score 2):

`<h2>A&eacute;roport Tunis Carthage</h2>` will do it.

Handy info on encoding can be found [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) and info on html character entities [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: @Paulie_D Since the screenreader supposedly works on *parsed* HTML, it should read just fine. It's not reading the `<h2>` out loud either after all.

Comment: Yeah it should be ok. If you like, there's info at http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/german.html (ok, it's German and not French, but the case is the same) and http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/tests/screen-readers/character-entities/

Comment: Looks like your font doesn't contain the character. What font are you using?

Comment: font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for displaying special characters in HTML:

1) Using [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). For example:

```
A&eacute;roport
```

2) Encoding the source HTML file appropriately (e.g. using UTF-8) and then indicating such encoding in the HTML head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Aéroport Tunis Carthage </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you have to use a text editor capable of writing files in the desired encoding. Otherwise you should indicate in the `<head>` the encoding used by the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your meta tags:

HTML4:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

HTML5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Source:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

EXAMPLE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Meta Tag -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- HTML5 -->

    <title> Your title here </title>

</head>
```

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` is shorter and equally effective. What is the relevance of your "Are you using HTML5?" question?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, both achieve the same job, it's just a copy and paste job, also my reasoning for asking if he was using HTML5 is because I believe that "<meta charset="utf-8">" was brought out for the purpose of HTML5 only

Comment: Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp : "Differences between HTML4 and HTML5"

Comment: @HmidiSlim I tested it out, and it worked fine on my browser, just to note, you'll need to include that in the head section of your website, i'll give an example in my answer

Comment: thank you it works ,but  when i put  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> (style.css is a stylesheet of a template which i downloaded ), i try <h2>Aéroport Tunis Carthage</h2> it doesn't work(the same font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif).

Comment: h2 {
   
 font-size:40px; 
 line-height:1.2em; 
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:normal;
 letter-spacing:-1px;
 margin-bottom:9px;
}

Comment: Np, Sorry just got back online and seen your message, Hmm.. does the rest of your styling work fine?

Comment: I tried it out here, seemed to work fine, Btw I changed the colour to black as white didn't show up on the page, view this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexCharlton/53tztz59/